# ErrorException Array to string conversion -- Error al enviar un array a una url

Tags: php, laravel-5, api

Estoy intentado enviar unos datos a un servicio API que estoy consumiendo, la ruta del servicio es tipo `resource` y debo enviar los datos a esa ruta. me aparece el siguiente error:

```
(1/1) ErrorException
Array to string conversion

in beneficiosController.php (line 69)
at HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Array to string conversion', '/Users/user/Desktop/users/app/Http/Controllers/transactionController.php', 69, array('request' => object(Request), 'client' => object(Client), 'data' => array('code' => '2270', 'item_code' => '82', 'user' => '555', 'pack_id' => '52', 'transaction_status' => '1', 'transaction_id' => null)))
```

**Estoy usando este control**

```
public function transaction(Request $request){

        $client = new Client();

        $data = [
            "code" =>  $request['code'],
            "item_code" => $request['item_code'],
            "user" => $request['user'],
            "pack_id" => $request['pack_id'],
            "transaction_status" => $request['transaction_status'],
            "transaction_id" => $request['transactransaction_idtion_status'],
            ];

        $response = $client->get("http://localhost:8000/v1/transaction". $data  );

        echo $response->getBody();

    }
```

¿Como debo enviar la url con el $data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estas usando `GuzzleHttp\Client`, la solución es pasar un `array` como segundo parámetro y dentro de este indicar [`form_params`](http://guzzle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/request-options.html#form-params) igual a `$data`.

Así por ejemplo:

```
$response = $client->get("http://localhost:8000/v1/transaction", [
  'form_params'=> $data
]);
```

Comment: Intenté pero obtuve: GET http://localhost:8000/v1/transaction` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response:

Comment: Ya funcionó. Tenia un error y lo arregle cambiando en el metodo GET por POST,

Answer (score 0):

Si necesitas pasar un Array por GET puede hacerlo con **http_build_query( )**

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
$data = array('foo'=>'bar',
          'baz'=>'boom',
          'cow'=>'milk',
          'php'=>'hypertext processor');

$data =  http_build_query($data);

$url= "http://localhost:8000/v1/transaction?". $data;
```

Documentación:

http://php.net/manual/es/function.http-build-query.php